# How to use the excel if function to return a variable concatenated with a string?

Tags: excel

If E1 is a cell, how do I return E1 dynamically concatenated with a string?

```
=IF(F1="not equal","update shop set url = E1 where id = A1","")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(F1="not equal","update shop set url = " & E1 & " where id = " & A1,"")
```